# TouchableOpacity onPress is not working, when I press on it, nothing happens

Tags: react-native

```
const UslugiScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
      <>
<View>
      <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.9} 
            style={styles.touch} 
            onPress={()=> {MiniMarketyScreen}}
            //onPress={()=>{navigation.push('MiniMarketyScreen')}}
            >  
            <View style={styles.view1}>
                <View style={{ marginBottom: 80 }}>
                    <Text style={styles.mainText}>
                        Минимаркеты </Text>
                    <Text>
                    }}>
                        Читать подробнее
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ width: 150, height: 150, marginRight: -45 }}>
                    <Image
                        source={require(`../images/minimarket1.jpg`)}
                        style={styles.image} />
                </View>
                <View
                    style={styles.view2}>
                    <View
                        style={styles.view3}>
                        <Entypo
                            name="credit-card"
                            style={{ fontSize: 18, color: '#000000' }} />
                    </View>
                    {/* <View style={styles.view4}>
                        <AntDesign name="star"
                            style={styles.antDesign} />
                        <Text style={styles.text}>
                            rating
                        </Text>
                    </View> */}
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
            </View>
            </>
    );
  };
export default UslugiScreen;
```

When I press on it, nothing happens, when I use navigation, it shows error The action 'PUSH' with payload {"name":"MiniMarketyScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'MiniMarketyScreen'?